# Replace span elements with table columns with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tables with columns and `<span>` elements where I want to replace the span element with <`td>` columns:

```
<td>
    <span>Chestnut Suede Boot</span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span>867008</span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span>8 eu 25.5</span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span>1</span>
    <br>
    <br>
    <span>10.00</span>
</td>
```

to look like:

```
<td>
    <td>Chestnut Suede Boot</td>
    <br>
    <br>
    <td>867008</td>
    <br>
    <br>
    <td>8 eu 25.5</td>
    <br>
    <br>
    <td>1</td>
    <br>
    <br>
    <td>10.00</td>
</td>
```

I have tried the following jQuery commands:

```
$('<td>').replaceAll('<span>');
```

but it does not work, if I do the following it seems to work and it replaces the td's with spans:

```
$('<span>').replaceAll('<td>');
```

Alternative I tried to convert the `<br>` to columns:

```
$('br').replaceAll('</td><td>');
```

so that the first `</td>` closes the top `<td>` and so on so that I have:

```
<td><span>Description</span></td>
<td></td>
<td><span>Item</span></td>
<td></td>
<td><span>Size</span></td>
<td></td>
<td><span>Qty</span></td>
<td></td>
<td><span>Price</span></td>
```

The problem is that it replace the `<br>` with `<td></td>` instead of `</td><td>`, which renders it incorrect.

Any help please?

Comment: you cannot have a td inside td, I dont think it is a good idea.

Comment: You can't nest one td inside another td. What are you trying to do?

Comment: You are right but it is not html code that I generate and have no control over, I probably will have to remove the top td if I get the spans converted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way of doing it

```
$('span').each(function() { 
     $(this).replaceWith($('<td'>+this.html()+'</td>')); 
});
```

Since td inside td will not work, it is much better to transform your HTML into semantically reasonable code by removing `<br>` e.g. via `$('td br').remove();`

```
<td>
  <div>
    <span>Chestnut Suede Boot</span>
    <span>867008</span>
    <span>8 eu 25.5</span>
    <span>1</span>
    <span>10.00</span>
  </div>
</td>
```

then use CSS to align it the way you want. To that extend, you can use  e.g.

```
td > div { display: table-row; }
td > div > span { display: table-cell; }
```

Comment: Your method works. Actually I have many tables with this content and I will have to combine it and in the process get the semantics correct.

Answer (score 1):

To replace tags using jQuery you can use replaceWith, passing a function as a parameter.

```
$('span').replaceWith(function(){
    return $("<td />", {html: $(this).html()});
});
```

But in your code I don't understand why you want a `td` inside another `td`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure if nesting td's is valid html, but the following code will get you there.

```
$('table tbody tr td span').replaceWith(function () {
    return '<td>' + this.innerHTML + '</td>';
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xW77R/